# push using git integration in DBeaver

Tags: dbeaver, git

I am using the git plugin for DBeaver. While I can commit, I am not seeing an option to push the commit over to master. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

If you trying to push a commit from a develop branch to master branch, you might need to do a pull request on GitHub. Once you merge the code on the server, then you can pull the code to your local.

Answer (score -1):

Check this out. Hope this helps
https://betterwithdata.substack.com/p/how-to-version-control-your-sql?s=r
Please see this along with the next response.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/182212)